# nesting polymer components doesn't work

Tags: polymer-2.x

I'm trying Polymer 2.0 for a project and I want to include custom elements inside a custom element (using an unnamed slot):

```
<my-overview-element>
    <my-child-element1></my-child-element1>
    <my-child-element2></my-child-element2>
    <my-child-element3></my-child-element3>
</my-overview-element>
```

When loading the page with my-overview-element the child elements are not visible. I do find them under the my-overview-element shadowRoot in DevTools but they are not rendered on the page (it seems they are not recognized as custom elements).
When navigating to another page containing `<my-child-element1>` (not as a child of a custom element) and then back to the overview page, the child element becomes visible. The same goes for my-child-element2 and 3. On their own pages the child elements are working fine.
Do I need some special commands to render custom elements as slotted children of another custom element? I tried lazy-importing them in the overview page but that doesn't help.

Comment: Can you also post the code for `my-overview-element`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you properly load all of them with something like this

```
<link rel="import" href="my-child-element1.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-child-element2.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-child-element3.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies and suggestions.
The problem was `lazy-import`: it seems to be a bit too lazy for importing child elements. Because it works for the main element on the page I didn't suspect `lazy-import` to be the culprit.
Using regular `import` for these elements solves the problem.